# Unable to fetch API response from TMDB

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build an app that displays the list of upcoming movie, popular movies, popular people, top ranked movies and a carousel slider that displays Now Playing movies. Although the all the calls are similar for upcoming movie, popular movies and top ranked movies, I am just able to see popular movie list on my app.

```
class MovieHomepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MovieHomepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MovieHomepage> createState() => _MovieHomepageState();
}

class _MovieHomepageState extends State<MovieHomepage> {
  List<MovieModel> popularMoviesList = [];
  List<MovieModel> upcomingMoviesList = [];
  List<MovieModel> topRatedMoviesList = [];

  Future<void> fetchmovies() async {
    //to get info from tmdb
    var popularMovieResponse = await ApiCall(Constants.popular).getData();
    var upcomingMovieResponse = await ApiCall(Constants.upcoming).getData();
    var topRatedMovieResponse = await ApiCall(Constants.topRated).getData();

    setState(() {
      // to get access to result part from the response
      List<dynamic> popularMoviesResults = popularMovieResponse['results'];
      List<dynamic> upcomingMoviesResults = upcomingMovieResponse['results'];
      List<dynamic> topRatedMoviesResults = topRatedMovieResponse['results'];


      //putting each element in form movieModel
      for (var element in popularMoviesResults) {
        popularMoviesList.add(MovieModel.fromJson(element));
      }
      for (var element in upcomingMoviesResults) {
        upcomingMoviesList.add(MovieModel.fromJson(element));
      }
      for (var element in topRatedMoviesResults) {
        topRatedMoviesList.add(MovieModel.fromJson(element));
      }
    });

  }

  //to perform api call each time the page is opened
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchmovies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //calling fetchmovies() inside the build() method can lead to an undesirable behavior.
    // The build() method should be used solely for building the UI and not for initiating asynchronous operations.
    //fetchmovies();

    print("Upcoming Movies Length: ${upcomingMoviesList.length}");
    print("Top Rated Movies Length: ${topRatedMoviesList.length}");
    print("Popular Rated Movies Length: ${popularMoviesList.length}");

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppBar(appBarTitle: 'mymovielist', icon: Icons.search),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    //now playing movie slider
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                      child: const NowPlayingMovies(),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    // Upcoming Movies
                    BuildMovieList(
                        title: "UPCOMING MOVIES", movieList: upcomingMoviesList),

                    //const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    // Popular Movies
                    BuildMovieList(
                        title: "POPULAR MOVIES", movieList: popularMoviesList),

                    //const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    // Top Rated Movies
                    BuildMovieList(
                        title: "TOP RANKED", movieList: topRatedMoviesList),

                    //const SizedBox(height:20.0),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // No built-in icon for a straight line
                          Container(
                            width: 6.0,
                            height: 32.0, // Width of the vertical line
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                          Text(
                            'POPULAR PEOPLE',
                            style:textTheme.bodyLarge,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, top: 10.0),
                      height: 200.0, // Provide a specific height here
                      child: const CelebritiesList(),
                    ),
                  ]))),
```

```
class ApiCall {
  static const String imagePathPrefix = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/';

  //pass url of the movies
  final String url;
  ApiCall(this.url);

  // Fetch data from API
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
      return responseBody;
    } else {
      // If the API call failed, throw an exception or handle the error accordingly
      throw Exception('Failed to load data from API');
    }
  }
}
```

```
class BuildMovieList extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildMovieList({ Key? key,required this.title, required this.movieList}): super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final List<MovieModel> movieList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Movie List Length: ${movieList.length}");
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        // Movie category Title
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 22.0, left: 8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              // No built-in icon for a straight line
              Container(
                width: 6.0,
                height: 32.0, // Width of the vertical line
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              // movie list name
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      title,
                      style: textTheme.bodyLarge,
                    ),

                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        // Handle the 'VIEW ALL' tap event here
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'VIEW ALL',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        // List View
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: movieList.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemExtent: 120.0,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // Handle the movie item tap event here
                },

                  child: MovieTile(movieIndex: index, movieList: movieList),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MovieTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<MovieModel> movieList;
  final int movieIndex;

  const MovieTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.movieList,
    required this.movieIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print("Movie Index: $movieIndex");
    // print("Movie Title: ${movieList[movieIndex].title}");

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.network(
              ApiCall.imagePathPrefix + movieList[movieIndex].poster_path,
              fit: BoxFit.cover, // Adjust the fit mode as needed
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const FaIcon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
                        size: 13.0,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 204, 0),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 7),
                      Text(
                        movieList[movieIndex].vote_average.toString(),
                        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 19.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // Add spacing between star/rating and movie title
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  movieList[movieIndex].title,
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium,
                  softWrap: false,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    print("Movie Index: $movieIndex");
  }
}
```

```
class MovieTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<MovieModel> movieList;
  final int movieIndex;

  const MovieTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.movieList,
    required this.movieIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print("Movie Index: $movieIndex");
    // print("Movie Title: ${movieList[movieIndex].title}");

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.network(
              ApiCall.imagePathPrefix + movieList[movieIndex].poster_path,
              fit: BoxFit.cover, // Adjust the fit mode as needed
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const FaIcon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
                        size: 13.0,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 204, 0),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 7),
                      Text(
                        movieList[movieIndex].vote_average.toString(),
                        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 19.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // Add spacing between star/rating and movie title
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  movieList[movieIndex].title,
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium,
                  softWrap: false,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    print("Movie Index: $movieIndex");
  }
}
```

I have tried debbuging using the print statement and have found out that

```
var popularMovieResponse = await ApiCall(Constants.popular).getData();
var upcomingMovieResponse = await ApiCall(Constants.upcoming).getData();
var topRatedMovieResponse = await ApiCall(Constants.topRated).getData();
```

and

```
  List<dynamic> popularMoviesResults = popularMovieResponse['results'];
  List<dynamic> upcomingMoviesResults = upcomingMovieResponse['results'];
  List<dynamic> topRatedMoviesResults = topRatedMovieResponse['results'];
```

part are fetching me the correct data from the website.

when I used

```
print("Upcoming Movies Length: ${upcomingMoviesList.length}");
print("Top Rated Movies Length: ${topRatedMoviesList.length}");
print("Popular Rated Movies Length: ${popularMoviesList.length}");
```

console:

I/flutter (27933): Upcoming Movies Length: 0
I/flutter (27933): Top Rated Movies Length: 0
I/flutter (27933): Popular Rated Movies Length: 13